# RPM + writing script in the spec file

Tags: linux, rpm-spec

is it possible to write ksh script in the spec file?

the target is during rpm -i my_rpm.rpm

according to the spec file , ksh script will do some installation & configuration

for example run other script and edit some files

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the shell to use in the script with `-p` I believe.

So it would look like:

```
%post -p /sbin/ldconfig
```

Or:

```
%post -p /bin/ksh
do_stuff_here
```

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlets in a spec file are normally executed by bash; however, if you need to use a different shell you could of course do that. Just write something like this:

```
cat > /tmp/script <<EOF
# write script here

EOF

ksh /tmp/script
```

OK, that is not very secure but you get the idea. This would be more secure, but I'm not sure if it would work:

```
ksh <<EOF
# write script here

EOF
```

Comment: hi if it not difficult did you have complete spec file with script?